# Hybris Cant Access comments filed of Customer

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris. My Requirement is to select all customers who have not left comments. I found that Comments have an author field and that I joined two fields of Customers and Comments. Also, I find out that Comment has a comment field which is a collection of comments. The problem is that I can't access to comment field to check if is it null or not.

```
SELECT * FROM {comment AS ct JOIN customer AS cr ON {ct:author}={cr:pk}} WHERE 

{ct:comment} IS NOT NULL
```

the exception that hac gives

Exception message: cannot search unknown field 'TableField(name='p_comment',langPK='null',type=comment)

it says there is no comment field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment model has text fields, I can't see Comment field on it. Use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM {comment AS ct JOIN customer AS cr ON {ct:author}={cr:pk}} 
WHERE {ct:text} IS NOT NULL
```